# NUnit tests refusing to run due to StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm not sure what is causing the exception here at all.

I had a number of tests which make use of NUnit TestCases, and these tests were all running fine with no issues. I then wrote an additional test which is almost identical to the others apart from a few variable values, and now none of my tests will run due to a StackOverflowException.

```
[05/10/2018 10:10:00 Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[05/10/2018 10:10:00 Informational] NUnit Adapter 3.10.0.21: Test execution started
[05/10/2018 10:10:00 Informational] Running all tests in C:\test.dll
[05/10/2018 10:10:00 Informational] NUnit3TestExecutor converted 9 of 9 NUnit test cases
[05/10/2018 10:10:04 Error] The active test run was aborted. Reason: Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.

[05/10/2018 10:10:04 Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:04.661362) ==========
```

Tests in another test class will run, however none of the tests in this class will run even if I comment out the other tests.

As you can see from the code below, most of the tests are structurally identical to the others, save for the variable names being passed as parameters and testcases.

```
[TestFixture]
    class FluentAddressValidatorTest
    {
        private FluentAddressValidator validator;

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            validator = new FluentAddressValidator();
        }

        [Test]
        public void FluentAddressValidatorAllowsValidAddressObject()
        {
            //Arrange
            FluentAddressValidator validator = new FluentAddressValidator();

            Address address = new Address();
            address = new Address
            {
                HouseNum = "1",
                HouseName = "Big House",
                StreetName = "Street",
                Locality = "Locality",
                Town = "Town",
                County = "County",
                Postcode = "NE11NM"
            };

            //Act
            ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(address);

            //Assert
            Assert.That(result.IsValid, Is.True);
        }

        [TestCase("1$")]
        [TestCase("1.")]
        [TestCase("32A.")]
        [TestCase("1        ")]
        public void FluentAddressValidatorDisallowsInvalidHouseNumber(string houseNum)
        {
            Address address = new Address
            {
                HouseNum = houseNum,
                HouseName = "House name",
                StreetName = "Street",
                Locality = "Locality",
                Town = "Town",
                County = "County",
                Postcode = "NE11NM"
            };

            validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(a => a.HouseNum, address);
        }

        [TestCase("House.Name")]
        [TestCase("House name.")]
        [TestCase("Housè")]
        [TestCase("")]
        [TestCase(" ")]
        [TestCase("House name House name House name House name House name")]
        public void FluentAddressValidatorDisallowsInvalidHouseName(string houseName)
        {
            Address address = new Address
            {
                HouseNum = "1a",
                HouseName = houseName,
                StreetName = "Street",
                Locality = "Locality",
                Town = "Town",
                County = "County",
                Postcode = "NE11NM"
            };

            validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(a => a.HouseName, address);
        }

        [TestCase("Street.Name")]
        [TestCase("Street name.")]
        [TestCase("Strèet")]
        [TestCase("")]
        [TestCase(" ")]
        [TestCase("Street name Street name Street name Street name Street name")]
        public void FluentAddressValidatorDisallowsInvalidStreetName(string streetName)
        {
            Address address = new Address
            {
                HouseNum = "1a",
                HouseName = "house",
                StreetName = streetName,
                Locality = "Locality",
                Town = "Town",
                County = "County",
                Postcode = "NE11NM"
            };

            validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(a => a.StreetName, address);
        }

        [TestCase("'Locality'")]
        [TestCase("Locality.")]
        [TestCase("Lòcality")]
        [TestCase("")]
        [TestCase(" ")]
        [TestCase("Locality Locality Locality Locality Locality Locality ")]
        public void FluentAddressValidatorDisallowsInvalidLocality(string locality)
        {
            Address address = new Address
            {
                HouseNum = "1a",
                HouseName = "house",
                StreetName = "Street name",
                Locality = locality,
                Town = "Town",
                County = "County",
                Postcode = "NE11NM"
            };

            validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(a => a.Locality, address);
        }

        [TestCase("'Town'")]
        [TestCase("Town.")]
        [TestCase("Tòwn")]
        [TestCase("")]
        [TestCase(" ")]
        [TestCase("Town Town Town Town Town Town Town Town Town Town")]
        public void FluentAddressValidatorDisallowsInvalidTown(string town)
        {
            Address address = new Address
            {
                HouseNum = "1a",
                HouseName = "house",
                StreetName = "Street name",
                Locality = "Locality",
                Town = town,
                County = "County",
                Postcode = "NE11NM"
            };

            validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(a => a.Town, address);
        }

        [TestCase("'County'")]
        [TestCase("County.")]
        [TestCase("Còunty")]
        [TestCase("")]
        [TestCase(" ")]
        [TestCase("County County County County County County")]
        public void FluentAddressValidatorDisallowsInvalidCounty(string county)
        {
            Address address = new Address
            {
                HouseNum = "1a",
                HouseName = "house",
                StreetName = "Street name",
                Locality = "Locality",
                Town = "Town",
                County = county,
                Postcode = "NE11NM"
            };

            validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(a => a.County, address);
        }

        [TestCase("'Postc0de'")]
        [TestCase("Ne11111.")]
        [TestCase("NXXXX12")]
        [TestCase("NXXXX!£2")]
        [TestCase("")]
        [TestCase(" ")]
        [TestCase("NE1                  1BN")]
        public void FluentAddressValidatorDisallowsInvalidPostcode(string postcode)
        {
            Address address = new Address
            {
                HouseNum = "1a",
                HouseName = "house",
                StreetName = "Street name",
                Locality = "Locality",
                Town = "Town",
                County = "County",
                Postcode = postcode
            };

            validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(a => a.Postcode, address);
        }
    }
```

FluentAddressValidator

```
public class FluentAddressValidator : AbstractValidator<Address>
    {
        private readonly string alphanumericalSpaceCaseInsensitiveRegex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$";
        private readonly string alphabeticalSpaceCaseInsensitiveRegex = "^[a-zA-Z ]*$";

        public FluentAddressValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(a => a.HouseNum).NotEmpty().MaximumLength(8).Matches(alphanumericalSpaceCaseInsensitiveRegex) //Not empty string, alphanumeric, allows spaces
                .WithMessage("House number must be alphanumerical only.");
            RuleFor(a => a.HouseName).NotEmpty().MaximumLength(32).Matches(alphabeticalSpaceCaseInsensitiveRegex) //Not empty string, alphabetical, includes spaces
                .WithMessage("House name must be alphabetical only."); 
            RuleFor(a => a.StreetName).NotEmpty().MaximumLength(32).Matches(alphabeticalSpaceCaseInsensitiveRegex) //Not empty string, alphabetical, includes spaces
                .WithMessage("Street name must be alphabetical only."); 
            RuleFor(a => a.Locality).NotEmpty().MaximumLength(32).Matches(alphabeticalSpaceCaseInsensitiveRegex) //Not empty string, alphabetical, includes spaces
                .WithMessage("Locality must be alphabetical only."); 
            RuleFor(a => a.Town).NotEmpty().MaximumLength(32).Matches(alphabeticalSpaceCaseInsensitiveRegex) //Not empty string, alphabetical, includes spaces
                .WithMessage("Town must be alphabetical only."); 
            RuleFor(a => a.County).NotEmpty().MaximumLength(32).Matches(alphabeticalSpaceCaseInsensitiveRegex) //Not empty string, alphabetical, includes spaces
                .WithMessage("County must be alphabetical only."); 
            RuleFor(a => a.Postcode).NotEmpty().MaximumLength(16).Must(Common.IsValidUkPostcode) //Not empty string, is valid uk postcode
                .WithMessage("Postcode must follow valid UK postcode format."); 
        }

    }
```

IsValidUkPostcode

```
public static bool IsValidUkPostcode(string postcode)
        {
            postcode = postcode.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
            postcode = postcode.ToUpper();

            Regex r = new Regex(@"([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9][A-Za-z]?))))\s?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})");

            if (r.IsMatch(postcode))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please post the source code of FluentAddressValidator? What nuget packages or libraries are you using?

Comment: If you comment out only the new test you wrote does it still fail? Also are your tests running in paralell?

Comment: @RuiJarimba I have added the class to the OP. I am using the FluentValidation library, which is what I'm testing within the above tests. And Nunit framework

Comment: @TheEdge I've tried commenting out all the tests except one but none of them run. How do I know if my tests are running in parallel?

Comment: I'm trying to compile the code but there are still things missing, could you please post the `Common.IsValidUkPostcode` code? No need for the full class, just enough to compile the code

Comment: @RuiJarimba I have added the method to the OP, is there anything else you require to compile the code?

Comment: I was able to compile the code and run the tests. All tests passed, I was not able to reproduce your issue. Try cleaning and rebuilding your solution, and maybe restart Visual Studio? :-)

Comment: @RuiJarimba I have already tried cleaning, rebuilding and restarting. Visual studio is updated to its latest version.

Comment: Weird. FYI I am using VS2017 Community Edition. My test project is a .NET Core 2.1 class library and I'm using the following nuget packages: `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk v15.8.0`, `FluentValidation v8.0.100`, `NUnit v3.10.1` and `NUnit3TestAdapter v3.10.0`

Comment: @RuiJarimba Rui, after some more experimentation I have found that the reason for the stack overflow is the Address class's properties. Changing these properties from a defined get and set to an auto property stops the exception from occuring. Any idea why the defined property is the issue?

Comment: I have auto-generated the class using Resharper, which creates auto-generated properties. Please post that as an answer. Also, edit your question and include the original class definition of Address. This is a very weird issue, well spotted!

Comment: @Jake12342134 you probably had properties with a backing field but you were referencing the property instead of the backing field? ;-)

Answer (score 6):

The cause of the StackOverflowException was due to the presence of Properties within the Address class that accidently made calls to itself recursively. This was not an issue with FluentValidation or NUnit.

For example:

```
public string Street
{
    get
    {
        return Street;
    }
    set
    {
        Street = value;
    }
}
```

This causes recursion and eventually will cause a stack overflow. To prevent this, have a private backing field that the property can delegate the data to.

```
private string street;

public string Street
{
    get
    {
        return this.street;
    }
    set
    {
        this.street = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's aggregating that even in 2021, C# still doesn't issue any compiler-warnings for recursive property invocations - not even a built-in code-analysis warning.